# How to add an environmental variable like NODE_ENV from a shell script to .profile?

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a shell script which automates the task of setting up any new EC2 instance. For that purpose, a prerequisite to that is setting up an environmental variable called `NODE_ENV='production'`. Now from a shell script I don't know how to access the profile file to add this line `export NODE_ENV='production'` at the bottom of .profile file?

Comment: It is same as accessing any other file.

Comment: I hope you realise that just adding lines to `.profile` will not affect the current process unless you "source" it?

Comment: @cdarke Yes then the next line to it would be source ~/.profile. Would that work?

Comment: @cdarke It didn't work. I am assuming this is what you warned me about. How do I source / reload it from the bash script?

Comment: `source ~/.profile` should do it, but if all you want is the variable then there is no need to write it to your start-up file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To append `export NODE_ENV='production'` at the bottom of `~/.profile`:

```
echo "export NODE_ENV='production'" >> ~/.profile
```

Comment: You need to prepend `export ` for it to become an _environment_ variable (otherwise it's just a _shell_ variable that child processes won't see).

Comment: Thank you and ++, but please just remove the ineffective version.